# Why is my linked list "next" pointer dereferencing to the wrong memory (XCode, C++)

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers, alignment, packing

Can someone please help me figure out why the "next" pointer in my linked list is dereferencing to the wrong memory address in code on 32-bit platform, but works fine on 64-bit platform?  My program is built as a universal binary on Xcode 7.3 and written in C++.

I've got a linked list, and dereferencing the "next" pointer in the debugger shows the correct memory, but dereferencing it in code reads the memory that is 4-bytes beyond where it should read.  I will try to explain..

The objects on the list are 4144 bytes each, the last 4-bytes are a 32-bit pointer to the "next" item on the list.  Looking at the "next" pointer in memory (0xBFFD63AC), we see that it is 4 zeros (NULL), this is correct.  BUT notice that memory at 0xBFFD63B0 is a 0x01.  This is the byte beyond the "next" pointer.  When I ask the debugger to print the next variable, it prints the proper value (NULL):

```
(lldb) print l_pObject->Next
(Object__t *) $0 = 0x00000000
(lldb) memory read &(l_pObject->Next)
0xbffd63ac: 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

However, if I execute the code that dereferences the "next" pointer, it actually reads the data from 0xBFFD63B0 instead of 0xBFFD63AC:

```
l_pObject = l_pObject->Next;

(lldb) print l_pObject
(Object_t *) $3 = 0x00000001
(lldb) memory read &(l_pObject)
0xbffd2504: 01 00 00 00 80 53 fd bf 00 00 00 00 6c 82 2e
```

I am positive it is reading the 0x01 from 0xBFFD63B0.  The debugger seems to know that "next" indicates the memory at 0xBFFD63AC, but for some reason dereferencing "next" in code actually reads from 0xBFFD63B0, but I'm not sure how to figure out why. I've tried adding `__attribute__((packed))` to the struct, but that made no difference.  It's difficult to determine where things are going wrong because the debugger is telling me something different from what is really happening.  Any tips on how to proceed from here would be very greatly appreciated!

**EDITED TO ADD MORE INFO:**

In the least there is a debugger error here!  I ask the debugger to print the sizeof the struct and it gives me 4144, but in code I use the C funciton sizeof() and that gives me 4148!  So there is definitely padding happening in the struct, but the debugger and apparently this section of code are blind to it.  This is the root of my problem.

Debugger:

```
(lldb) print sizeof(*l_pObject)
```

(unsigned long) $0 = 4144

Code:

```
unsigned int iSizeOf = sizeof(*l_pObject); /* iSizeOf will equal 4148! */
```

Something funny is happening...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is impossible to tell. In general though, pointers tend to be 8-bytes wide on 64-bit systems and 4-bites wide on 32-bit systems. Obviously you observed that it's jumping 4 bytes beyond where it should be, which is a strong indicator. `(0xBFFD63B0 - 0xBFFD63AC) == 4`.

Comment: I would post the entire code if I could, but it's probably 50+ files and tens of thousands of lines.  BUT I found part of what's causing my headache!  The debugger is lying.  I edited my original post above to show.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the problem, I should have realized it right away.  The code that was crashing is in a library.  Both the library and the calling application share definitions for variable types.  Due to a missing preprocessor flag on the application side, one of those types was being allocated 4-bytes smaller on the application side than in the library code.  So when the application created a linked list of objects and passed a reference to the library, each object on that list was 4-bytes smaller than the library was expecting them to be.  What made it less obvious was the debugger was showing me addresses and offsets based on what was allocated in the application, so at first glance everything appeared to be sized correctly.  I decided to not trust the debugger and wrote my own code to check addresses and offsets, and that's when it became obvious what was happening.  So anyway, long story short, be sure your application and library allocate types to be the same size and then things will work much better. :)